# Callback function that accepts more parameters

Tags: javascript, callback

I have the following method added to an object :

```
loadAPIServiceData : function(service, format, term, callback) {
        return $.when($.ajax({
            url: service + ((term) ? term : '') + '?format=' + format
        })).done(function(result) {
            return callback.apply(result, [ result ]);
        });
    },
```

The callback function is passed one parameter that I need further down in the chain when I'm loading the data ( the `result` obviously gets whatever I get back from the AJAX call ). What I need is to be able to add more parameters to the callback function when it's called, and still have the `result` in there :)

To be more explicit about it this is what I was meaning when I said "*I need is to be able to add more parameters to the callback function when it's called, and still have the `result` in there*" :

```
var test = loadAPIServiceData('some_service', 'json', 'some_term', function(result, another_parameter, ...) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for apply arguments without need to modify the `loadAPIServiceData`:

```
function myCallback(arg1, arg2, result) {
    //
}

loadAPIServiceData(service, format, term, myCallback.bind(this, arg1, arg2));
```

If you prefer keep `result` in first arg position, this code send all additional argument to the callback, using the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

```
loadAPIServiceData : function(service, format, term, callback) {
    var add_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 4);

    return $.when($.ajax({
        url: service + ((term) ? term : '') + '?format=' + format
    })).done(function(result) {
        return callback.apply(this, result, [ result].concat(add_args));
    });
},

function myCallback(result, arg1, arg2) {
    //
}

loadAPIServiceData(service, format, term, myCallback, "arg1", "arg2");
```

Comment: Could I do it like so : `loadAPIServiceData(service, format, term, function(result, arg1, arg2, arg3 ....){});` if I call the slice and the concat ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. With this code, you need to set the arguments when you call `loadAPIServiceData`. But if you ask if you can use a anonymous function, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but does this make sense?

```
function addOptionalParams(result) {
    var params = [];
    params.push(result);

    // do logic to decide if you need more params
    // if you need more params, push them to the params array
    if(weNeedMoreParams) {
        params.push('foo');
        params.push('bar');
    }

    return params;
}

loadAPIServiceData : function(service, format, term, callback) {
    return $.when($.ajax({
        url: service + ((term) ? term : '') + '?format=' + format
    })).done(function(result) {
        var callbackArgs = addOptionalParams(result);

        return callback.apply(this, callbackArgs);
    });
},
```

It is the 'done' function which determines which parameters it will invoke the callback with.

Comment: That's the thing, I won't have any parameters or variables inside the done function, I will only pass more parameters when calling the function, so it's like an optional parameter which can be omitted if I don't have it ...

Comment: @Roland check edited answer, also the .apply method should take the context as first parameter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply